# How to exec a stored procedure for a list of constant values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I can exec a stored procedure for a single value easily:

```
EXEC FooStored @ID = 269
```

But how can I execute the same stored for many values, which I have in a list (I have a comma separated list of about 1000 constant values, which came from outside of SQL).

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
EXEC FooStored @ID IN (269,270,274,280,282,292,300,320,324)  -- doesn't work
```

Edit: Since I don't have permissions to alter this procedure or make new stored procedures to this DB, I would prefer to solve this on the querying level, rather than ask someone to make the needed changes for me.

Comment: A [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) would be best. Another option is passing the delimited list as a single string and then splitting the values.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm not familiar with either of those techniques. Would you mind expanding your comment into an answer?

Comment: What is your SQL version?

Comment: If you don't want to change the existing procedure, then the best option would be to copy the current stored procedure and change the copy to work with a table valued parameter. I know that it kinda violates DRY but that's usually less important in SQL then in programming.

Comment: @Zhorov SQL Server 2016

Comment: @ZoharPeled Added an edit to my question, which clears up my reasoning.

Comment: @ruohola you should be prepared to accept responsibility for possible low performing query times, if you choose to go to this route where the only way to solve your problem is by calling the stored procedure with every parameter. If performance is unacceptable, the only solution would be to go the way DanGuzman suggested, where eventually you will need to find someone who can change the procedure for you.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Yeah, the momentary bad performance will not be an issue.

Comment: @ruohola it usually never is *now*, but this type of problem usually scales really fast up to the point where you need to tackle the stored procedure code. Good luck!

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu This is luckily a one off thing (at least I hope :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ikram and @DanGuzman said, the only way to do this, without editing the existing procedure or making a new one, is to just exec the stored N times. The query can be built quite fast with for example Vim.

Starting from the file (a lot more numbers in reality):

```
269,270,274,280,282,292,300,320,324
```

And running the commands:

```
qqf,s<Enter><Esc>q
1000@q
<C-V>ggIEXEC FooStored @ID =
```

Result:

```
EXEC FooStored @ID = 269
EXEC FooStored @ID = 270
EXEC FooStored @ID = 274
EXEC FooStored @ID = 280
EXEC FooStored @ID = 282
EXEC FooStored @ID = 292
EXEC FooStored @ID = 300
EXEC FooStored @ID = 320
EXEC FooStored @ID = 324
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example using a table-valued parameter.

I see from your comment on the string-splitting answer that you don't want to modify the existing stored procedure interface. Consider creating a new stored procedure for the list interface or overloading the existing interface with the optional list parameter to avoid a breaking change.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntegerList AS TABLE(
    IntegerValue int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    )
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.FooStored
    @IntegerList dbo.IntegerList READONLY
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID IN(
    SELECT IntegerValue
    FROM @IntegerList
);
GO

DECLARE @IntegerList dbo.IntegerList;
INSERT INTO @IntegerList VALUES(269),(270),(274),(280),(282),(292),(300),(320),(324);
EXEC dbo.FooStored @IntegerList = @IntegerList;
GO
```

Comment: Added an edit to my question, which clears up my needs.

Comment: @ruohola, there is no T-SQL solution if you can't change the proc or create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Table types
In your stored procedure use a user defined table type as type of your value.
it could be some thing like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FooStored 
(
    @IDs ListOfID READONLY
)
AS
.
.
.
```

ListOfID is a user defined table type as you can see it below:

```
CREATE TYPE ListOfID AS TABLE
(
    [ID] int NULL
)
```

to use your FooStored stored procedure you must at first declare a temp table and insert your data into that temp Table and pass your it to your stored procedure.
it could be some thing like this:

```
 DECLARE @list ListOfID
    INSERT INTO @list VALUES(1)
    INSERT INTO @list VALUES(2)
    EXEC FooStored @list
```

Comment: Thanks, but I edited my question to state that I would prefer not to edit the existing procedure.

Comment: So the only way to do that is to execute your stored procedure as many times as the length of your list

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case, my submitted answer also reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take parameter as comma separated string into stored procedure, and then **check inside the stored procedure** **"if '@ID' is in the list."**

If you are using **SQL Server 2016 and above** you can use `SPLIT_STRING() function`.

If you are using **lower version of SQL Server** then you can use this function to split the string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

To split the string inside stored procedure:

```
IF (@ID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring(@CommaSeparatedString))
```

**NB!** Be careful with white spaces when using above `splitstring` function. For values like **'269, 270, 274'** -> space after commas:

```
IF (@ID IN (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM([Name])) FROM dbo.splitstring(@CommaSeparatedString))
```

Comment: I would prefer overloading stored procedure by adding optional parameter As @Dan Guzman said. This way other users will not affect from your change

Comment: Added an edit to my question, which clears up my reasoning.

Comment: If you have no right to alter or create a new sp, then the only way is to calling sp N times I think

Comment: That might be the case... To bad if it really is.